# TCP 3-Way Handshake is merely OS responsibility?

Tags: nginx, tcp

While loadtesting an nginx (side B) with WRK (side A) i'm seeing a few TCPSynRetrans. For a 180sec run the number of TCPSynRetrans is less than 10 for around 400ish req/sec (according to wrk final report).

`wrk -t 1 -c 50 -d 180s -H 'Connection: close' https://<B_IP>/static/0kb.bin`

From the captures i see a SYN from A that is not anwsered by B

After 1sec A retransmits the SYN and B then anwsers with [SYN,ACK]

I see that the SYN arrives at the target nginx by looking at packet captures. The connections are also closing properly so i'm not building a queue of time waiting connections. I've also verified that i have no problem with the syn_backlog queue (netstat -ant | grep -c SYN_REC) and don't see any ListenDrops ListenOverflows.

So i'm wondering it is safe to assume that the 3-way handshake **is solely and OS responsibility** and continue to follow that line of investigation?

Any hints on how to take the troubleshooting further are also appreciated, hping3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal applications use socket interface to access TCP sockets. The socket interface abstracts away the lower level details of TCP connections like handshakes, retransmissions etc.

So, your assumption is correct that the network stack is responsible for TCP three way handshake.

> I see that the SYN arrives at the target nginx by looking at packet captures.

This statement is incorrect. nginx does not see SYN packets. The network stack on the server where nginx runs sees SYN packets.

nginx only sees bytes coming into socket which is bound to a certain TCP port.

https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/why-are-linux-kernel-protocol-stacks-dropping-syn-packets_595251 contains some information on why SYN packets are dropped occasionally.

Comment: "SYN arrives at the target nginx by looking at packet captures" was sort of speak i should have said arrive at the target host.

Your link was really helpful, in the meanwhile I started to get some runs free of TCPSynRetrans ?!
I check my target host and the kernel is 4.15.0 so it no longer has `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle`. I'll keep an eye on "passive connections rejected because of time stamp" and pro-actively increase the SYN backlog and Listen Backlog queue in the hope that this issue doesn't reoccur. I'll keep you posted, kudos